# How to prevent users to use non registered connected apps

Tags: api, connected-apps, oauth

There are many web applications that connect to Salesforce with OAuth without configure a connected app (e.g. onegraph).

How can we prevent users to connect such an application?

Comment: Applications can't connect via oAuth without a connected app. Onegraph is no exception to this rule, they simply didn't document this.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_manage_current_sessions.htm&type=5

Setup --> Connected Apps OAuth Usage

[image]

Here you should see all connected apps, the user count, and the option to "block".

You could block the app which it sounds like you want.

Or you can even revoke certain users connection so they have to re-login in by clicking into users and selecting "revoke".

Comment: Thank you @Kris for your answers but what I am actually asking is how can we prevent connection before the user are connected. Do you have an idea for this?